# Is it possible to show a link in a C# program to the admin only?

Tags: c#, web-config, privileges, createuserwizard

Hi (I'm pretty new to this),

I have a login control in my C# program and once the user logs in, they are able to see links to other programs (a portal). Is it possible to hide the 'create new user' link to everyone except the admin once the user has logged in? Is this something I'd change in the web.config as I only want admins to be able to create new users (I use a CreateUserWizard for this).

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with 'admin', is it a role in your application? Do you mean the current logged in windows user?

Comment: I'm the admin and have set this up in the asp.net configuaration so I was wondering if it is possible so that only I can see the link to 'create user' and for all the other users, this text does not show.
In my web.config I have added: <location path="CreateUser.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="admin"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that 'admin' is a role in your application. If so, you can use a [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control.

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
            <ContentTemplate>
                Stuff only an administrator can see
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

You can also do in programatically, using the [IsUserInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.isuserinrole.aspx) method, e.g:

```
somePanel.Visible = Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin");
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, you wish to only allow access to, and display, pages to an authenticated user in an asp.net website who is in particular role (in this case, the "admin" role)?

To do this you need to enable [security trimming on your site map provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx) eg.

```
 <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider"
        description="Default SiteMap provider."
        type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider "
        siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"
        securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
    </providers>
  </siteMap>
```

This will tell your sitemap provider to take account of whether members are authenticated and what roles they are in when displaying menu items.

To actually block access to paths via location paths and roles in the web.config  For instance:

```
<location path="~/CreateNewUser.aspx">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
   <allow roles="Admin"/>
   <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

See [How To: Use Role Manager in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx) for a full overview.

Comment: Yep it is an admin role. Works a treat now so only the admin can view the page - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in your codebehind:

```
createUserLink.Visible = currentUser.IsAdmin;
```

Answer (score 0):

The LoginView control can display certain content depending on the user role.